# Which equation is used for calculation interest rate of lump sum?

Tags: time-value

I was watching CFA level1 videos and found this odd question.

> Elmer has won his $4 million state lottery and has been offered 20 annual payments of $200,000 each beginning today or a single payment of $2,267,000. What is the annual discount rate used to calculate the lump-sum payout amount?

```
I know how to type in calculator by 
Begin Mode, N=20, FV=0, PMT=-200,000, PV=2,267,000
ANS: I/Y = 7%
```

However, I am interested in mathematical calculation. I have tried EMI, i=N√FVPV−1, etc. equations. Doesn't see one of them working.
I am wondering which equation is used for calculation interest rate of lump sum? Why following formula doesn't work?
-200,000 * (I/Y**20) = 2,267,000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you accepted the $200,000 per year you could deposit each payment at zero interest and end up with $4m after 20 years.  If you accepted the single payment of $2,267,000 you would have to deposit it in a bank at 2.87987 % per annum to end up with $4m after 20 years.

```
4000000 = 2267000 (1 + r)^20 ∴ r = 2.87987 %
```

The OP only asks for the single payment calculation.  Nevertheless, here is the rest.

The advantage of annual payments would remain up until the bank deposit rate reached slightly over 7% at which point the advantage turns to the single payment. I.e. [future value of an annuity due](https://www.investopedia.com/retirement/calculating-present-and-future-value-of-annuities/) for the annual payments:

Future value `s` equals the sum of the appreciated payments `a`. Formula is by [induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1039800/119821).

[image: annuity due]

Choosing `r` slightly over 7% for an example

```
  r = 0.070008
  a = 200000
  n = 20
∴ s = (a (1 + r) ((1 + r)^n - 1))/r = $8,773,867.36
```

vs. single payment

```
2267000 (1 + 0.070008)^20 = $8,773,886.56
```

In this case the future value from the single payment is greater.

With `r > 7.00077 %` is it advantageous to take the single payment.  The plot below illustrates the cross-over point with the exact intercept found by solver.

Note the answer as stated by the OP is 7%.

[image]

Solution via solver

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical calculation is an iterative root-finding algorithm. There's not a known closed form equation for the interest rate that results in a specific present value, except for very simple cases like a single cash flow.  So the calculator tries various interest rates until it finds one that gives the correct present value of the coupon stream.

> Why following formula doesn't work? -200,000 * (I/Y**20) = 2,267,000

It looks like you're trying to calculate the *future value* of a cash flow, but are comparing it to the *present value*. The idea of present value is "At what interest rate could I invest 2,267,000 now, and 200k per year, and end up with the same amount in the end".

Comment: Thank you. That make senses. No wonder I couldn't find any formulas. Appreciate it!!!

Answer (score -1):

FV = PV (1+r)^n

This will help you.

Comment: Indeed `4000000 = 2267000 (1 + r)^20 ∴ r = 2.87987 %`

Comment: For this to be useful, define the variables and explain why the formula works.